# Having a problem creating a color fade effect on menu items using jquery, html and css

Tags: jquery, html, css

For giggles, I'm creating an image free, but interacting website. On the menu, I want each item to fade to gray on `mouseover`, and then fade back to white on `mouseout`. Currently, all of the menu items fade in unison. For many who inspect my code, you'll surely see why in quick time. I'm just too new to it.

Link to site: [Zero Img Site](http://bigsilkdesign.com/zero_img_site/index_play.html)

jQuery stuff:

```
<head>
    <title>Imageless Website in HTML5, jQuery and CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/CreateHTML5Elements.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/color/jquery.color.js"></script>

</head>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".block").mouseover(function(){
        $(".block").animate( { backgroundColor: '#777777' }, 100)
    });
        $(".block").mouseout(function(){
        $(".block").animate( { backgroundColor: 'white' }, 200)
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML Stuff:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">
    <div class="block">
        home
    </div>
</a>

<a href="http://www.example.com">
    <div class="block">
        about
    </div>

</a>

<a href="http://www.example.com">
    <div class="block">
        contact
    </div>
</a>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the .block selectors in the mouseover functions so they simply act on the element you are mouseovering. You do this by using the keyword this.

```
$(".block").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor: '#777777' }, 100)
});
$(".block").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate( { backgroundColor: 'white' }, 200)
});
```

Comment: Copied and pasted, didn't work. No reaction from the menu item elements. They remain white on 'mouseover'.

Comment: It works for me. The code I've given still has to go inside 
$(document).ready(function(){});
Can't think of anything else that might stop it working. Do you get any javascript errors in your console?

Comment: Syntax Error: [Break on this error] $(.this).animate( { backgroundColor: '#777777' }, 100)\n

Comment: I've uploaded the edited page to the link in the original comment.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Just recognized problem. Thank you.